# How to solve the index not found error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have try to code the hangman game in python. I have all the code completed I think there is some minor mistakes in my code that is why i am getting index not found error.

```
# Import statements: DO NOT delete these! DO NOT write code above this!
from random import randrange
from string import *

# -----------------------------------
# Helper code
# (you don't need to understand this helper code)
# Import hangman words
WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

# CONSTANTS
MAX_GUESSES = 6

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
secret_word = 'claptrap'
letters_guessed = []
space = ""

def word_guessed():
    '''
    Returns True if the player has successfully guessed the word,
    and False otherwise.
    '''
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed

    ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
    flag = 0
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if letters_guessed[i] != secret_word[i]:
            flag = 1
    
    if flag == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    # pass  # This tells your code to skip this function; delete it when you
    # start working on this function


# print_guessed function
def print_guessed():
    '''
    Prints out the characters you have guessed in the secret word so far
    '''
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    global space
    ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
    empty = "_"
    
    for letter in secret_word:
        space += letter if letter.lower() in letters_guessed else empty
    # pass  # This tells your code to skip this function; delete it when you
    # start working on this function
    print(space)


# play_hangman function
def play_hangman():
    # Actually play the hangman game
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    # Put the mistakes_made variable here, since you'll only use it in this function
    mistakes_made = 0

    # Update secret_word. Don't uncomment this line until you get to final steps.
    # secret_word = get_word()
    print('Starting game')
    while mistakes_made <= MAX_GUESSES:
        guess = input("Guess a character: ")
        if guess in secret_word:
            letters_guessed.append(guess)
            print_guessed()
            if len(space) == len(secret_word):
                if word_guessed():
                    break
        else:
            print("Incorrect guess.")
            mistakes_made += 1
    ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
    if mistakes_made == MAX_GUESSES:
        print("The secret word is", secret_word)


# Strt the game
play_hangman()
```

I am facing this error.

> if letters_guessed[i] != secret_word[i]:
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: ```letters_guessed``` is empty. It doesn't have any index. That is why an error

Comment: That I also know but how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `secret_word` is a string, so put `secret_word[i]` is the wrong way. what if `letters_guessed` is None, it will return error. So you need to replace `for i in range(len(letters_guessed)` with `for i in letters_guessed`. Here is the code:

```
flag = 0
for i in letters_guessed:
    if i != secret_word:
        flag = 1
```

EDIT: If you have the problem the empty space and word multiple every times you input, here the answer.

```
# Import statements: DO NOT delete these! DO NOT write code above this!
from random import randrange
from string import *

# -----------------------------------
# Helper code
# (you don't need to understand this helper code)
# Import hangman words
WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

# CONSTANTS
MAX_GUESSES = 6

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
secret_word = 'claptrap'
letters_guessed = []
space = ""

def word_guessed():
    '''
    Returns True if the player has successfully guessed the word,
    and False otherwise.
    '''
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed

    ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
    flag = 0
    for i in letters_guessed:
        if i != secret_word:
            flag = 1
    
    if flag == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    # pass  # This tells your code to skip this function; delete it when you
    # start working on this function


# print_guessed function
def print_guessed():
    '''
    Prints out the characters you have guessed in the secret word so far
    '''
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    global space
    ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
    empty = "_"
    
    for letter in secret_word:
        space += letter if letter.lower() in letters_guessed else empty
    if space == secret_word:
        print('You win')
        exit()
    # pass  # This tells your code to skip this function; delete it when you
    # start working on this function
    print(space)
    # You must config space to None before input again
    space = ''


# play_hangman function
def play_hangman():
    # Actually play the hangman game
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    # Put the mistakes_made variable here, since you'll only use it in this function
    mistakes_made = 0

    # Update secret_word. Don't uncomment this line until you get to final steps.
    # secret_word = get_word()
    print('Starting game')
    while mistakes_made <= MAX_GUESSES:
        guess = input("Guess a character: ")
        if guess in secret_word and guess:
            letters_guessed.append(guess)
            print_guessed()
            if len(space) == len(secret_word):
                if word_guessed():
                    break
        else:
            print("Incorrect guess.")
            mistakes_made += 1
    ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
    if mistakes_made == MAX_GUESSES:
        print("The secret word is", secret_word)


# Strt the game
play_hangman()
```

You need to convert the showing word to None before the user enter the next word, check if word is right will the right way.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. But now I am facing another error. It is asking for a character also if I guessed the word. How to break the loop so that if word is guessed by the user then end the loop?

Comment: I have edited and now it will work properly for you.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the empty letter_guessed variable, you get the following error.

IndexError: list index out of range